# Windows Server 2012 guest machine no internet or LAN

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012, hyper-v-server-2012, internet

I have a windows server 2012 with hyper-v added as a feature. I have created a server 2012 and a windows 8 guest machines. The windows 8 machine has internet connectivity and can successfully be added to our AD domain. I can log in to the domain on this guest machine with an AD account. However the server 2012 guest machine cannot be joined to the domain and does not have internet connectivity. Strangely enough (to me!). Is there any special settings/config that I should be doing/have missed?!

Comment: Have you assigned an appropriate ip address, subnet mask, default gateway and DNS server(s) on the NIC on the W2K12 server?

Comment: I have assigned the nic on the win 2k12 VM a static IP and the default gateway of our router and dns of our DC (basically the same credentials I would of given a physical box on the network....)

Comment: What's the W2K12's Network Configuration in it's Properties in Hyper-V Manager?

Comment: I'm referring to the W2K12 guest machine.

Comment: Correct, the NIC(s) being connected to vSwitches should not be messed with, only the Microsoft Virtual Network Switch Protocol enabled (unless it's a teamed interface, then there will probably be some teaming protocol as well)

Comment: SOLVED! I had 'Enable virtual LAN identification' checked. Unchecked it, jobs a good'en! Thanks to all and especially Chris S!

Comment: Would you post that as an Answer please, and "Accept" it when you can? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED! I had 'Enable virtual LAN identification' checked. Unchecked it, jobs a good'en!

Comment: Where is that setting?

Comment: OK it is a Hyper-v machine setting.